# V-22 aerial refueling

Tags: refueling, v-22

Boeing worked on an aerial refueling pod for the V-22 that can both refuel other aircraft in air and be offloaded to provide fuel to land vehicles. That seems like a no brainer for the British to purchase as well as any other navy that doesn't have on-ship tankers like the F/A-18 or upcoming Stingray tanker as well as a great addition to disaster relief efforts.

Why has there been no progress for years on that project?

https://news.usni.org/2015/07/29/davis-v-22-aerial-refueling-system-should-be-ready-for-early-f-35-operations-despite-1-year-delay

https://boeing.mediaroom.com/Bell-Boeing-V-22-Osprey-Deploys-Refueling-Equipment-in-Flight-Test

Comment: Would be good to add some links to which Boeing system you are referring, since this is an active area of with various projects, submissions and actual products around. Short answer would be that governments try not to spend ALL the tax payer money on shiney stuff, so there will always be cool things left on the shelf.